# A bound for a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have two positives sequences $a$ and $b$ such that $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to 0.$

Let $$U_n=\left(\frac{1}{(a_n-b_n)^2}-\frac{1}{a_n^2}\right)=\frac{1}{a_n^2}\left(\frac{1}{\left( 1-\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right)^2}-1\right)$$

Is it possible to get a bound for $U_n$ other than $\frac{K}{a_n^2}?$ ($K$ is constant) I asked this question because in my problem I have $a_n^2U_n$ so I get $a_n^2U_n\le C$ and I would like something which depends on $n.$

> **EDIT:** sorry I will change a bit the question, because in my case $a$ and $b$ converge to $+\infty$, so it-is possible to get a bound that converge to $0$ ?

Comment: What is the definition of $U_n$?

Comment: Your second definition of $U_n$ is different from the first.

Comment: Exactly @Ingix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: 
$$(1-\frac{a_n}{b_n})^{-2}-1 \sim 2\frac{a_n}{b_n}.$$

Comment: Actually, it does work: you get $U_n \sim\frac{C}{a_nb_n}=\frac{C}{a_n^2}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=o(a_n^{-2})$.

Comment: Then $V_n \sim C\frac{a_n^2}{a_nb_n}=C\frac{a_n}{b_n}=o(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

In case the hint is not enough (try to work with it first):

With $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$, we get

$$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}1-\frac{a_n}{b_n} & = & 1-0=1 \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{a_n}{b_n})^2 & = & 1^2=1 \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1-\frac{a_n}{b_n})^2} & = & \frac11=1 \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^2U_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1-\frac{a_n}{b_n})^2}-1 & = & 1-1=0 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I don't understand your problem. No matter how $a_n,b_n$ behave individually, if you assume their quotient tends to 0, you get the result $a_n^2U_n \to 0$. What more do you want?